# Get two neighboring non-nan values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, nan, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have a numpy array

```
my_array = [0.2, 0.3, nan, nan, nan, 0.1, nan, 0.5, nan]
```

For each nan value, I want to extract the two non-nan values to the left and right of that point (or single value if appropriate). So I would like my output to be something like

```
output = [[0.3,0.1], [0.3,0.1], [0.3,0.1], [0.1,0.5], [0.5]]
```

I was thinking of looping through all the values in my_array, then finding those that are nan, but I'm not sure how to do the next part of finding the nearest non-nan values.

Comment: Can you explain the example? It makes little sense to me, e.g. input has 9 values, 4 of them are not nan, and the output is a list of 5 pairs, except the last one and the values in pairs for 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 are the same..

Comment: There are 5 nan values in my_array. There are 5 pairs in output, one for each nan value. For each nan-value, I want the non-nan values to its left and right. So the first three nan values have 0.3 and 0.1 on their left and right, the fourth has 0.1 and 0.5 on the left and right, and the final nan value just has 0.5 on the left.

Comment: do you mind using pandas?

Comment: no, I don't mind using pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pandas and numpy:

```
s = pd.Series([0.2, 0.3, nan, nan, nan, 0.1, nan, 0.5, nan])
m = s.isna()
a = np.vstack((s.ffill()[m], s.bfill()[m]))
out = a[:,~np.isnan(a).any(0)].T.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.1, 0.5]]
```

*NB. You can choose to keep or drop the lists containing NaNs.*

With NaNs:

```
out = a.T.tolist()

[[0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.1, 0.5], [0.5, nan]]
```

##### alternative to handle the single elements:

```
s = pd.Series([0.2, 0.3, nan, nan, nan, 0.1, nan, 0.5, nan])
m = s.isna()

(pd
 .concat((s.ffill()[m], s.bfill()[m]), axis=1)
 .stack()
 .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
 .to_list()
 )
```

Output:

```
[[0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.1, 0.5], [0.5]]
```

Comment: Note that everything could be done with only numpy, but pandas' `ffill`/`bfill` are really convenient.

Answer (score 3):

Less elegant than @mozway's answer, but the last list only has one element:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'left':arr.ffill(), 
    'right': arr.bfill()
}).loc[arr.isna()].apply(lambda row: row.dropna().to_list(), axis=1).to_list()
```

Comment: I fixed it to drop the Nan ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of education, I'll post a pretty straight-forward algorithm for achieving this result, which works by finding the closest index of a value to the left and to the right of each index of a NaN, and filters out any infs at the end:

```py
def get_neighbors(x: np.ndarray) -> list:
    mask = np.isnan(x)
    nan_idxs, *_ = np.where(mask)
    val_idxs, *_ = np.where(~mask)

    neighbors = []
    for nan_idx in nan_idxs:
        L, R = -float("inf"), float("inf")
        for val_idx in val_idxs:
            if val_idx < nan_idx:
                L = max(L, val_idx)
            else:
                R = min(R, val_idx)
        # casting to list isn't strictly necessary, you'll just end up with a list of arrays
        neighbors.append(list(x[[i for i in (L, R) if i > 0 and i < float("inf")]]))

    return neighbors
```

Output:

```py
>>> get_neighbors(my_array)
[[0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.3, 0.1], [0.1, 0.5], [0.5]]
```

The nested `for` loop has a worst-case runtime of `O((n / 2)^2)` where `n` is the number of elements of `x` (worst case occurs when exactly half the elements are NaN).

Answer (score 1):

I was eager to check how could use just NumPy to solve this problem as an exercise. After some hours I could reach a solution :), but as I think it will be inefficient comparing to pandas as mentioned by *Mozway*, I didn't optimized the code further (it can be optimized; if conditions may could be cured and merged in other sections):

```
my_array = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 0.2, 0.3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.1, 0.7, np.nan, 0.5])

nans = np.isnan(my_array).astype(np.int8)           # [1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
zeros = np.where(nans == 0)[0]                      # [ 2  3  7  8 10]
diff_nan = np.diff(nans)                            # [ 0 -1  0  1  0  0 -1  0  1 -1]
start = np.where(diff_nan == 1)[0]                  # [3 8]
end = np.where(diff_nan == -1)[0] + 1               # [ 2  7 10]

mask_start_nan = np.isnan(my_array[0])              # True
mask_end_nan = np.isnan(my_array[-1])               # False

if mask_end_nan: start = start[:-1]                 # [3 8]
if mask_start_nan: end = end[1:]                    # [ 7 10]
inds = np.dstack([start, end]).squeeze()            # [[ 3  7] [ 8 10]]
initial = my_array[inds]                            # [[0.3 0.1] [0.7 0.5]]

repeats = np.diff(np.where(np.concatenate(([nans[0]], nans[:-1] != nans[1:], [True])))[0])[::2]    # [2 3 1]
if mask_end_nan: repeats = repeats[:-1]             # [2 3 1]
if mask_start_nan: repeats = repeats[1:]            # [3 1]

result = np.repeat(initial, repeats, axis=0)        # [[0.3 0.1] [0.3 0.1] [0.3 0.1] [0.7 0.5]]
if mask_end_nan: result = np.array([*result, np.array(my_array[zeros[-1]])], dtype=object)
if mask_start_nan: result = np.array([np.array(my_array[zeros[0]]), *result], dtype=object)

# [array(0.2) array([0.3, 0.1]) array([0.3, 0.1]) array([0.3, 0.1]) array([0.7, 0.5])]
```

I don't know if there be a much easier solution by NumPy; I implemented what came to my mind. I believe that this code can be greatly improved (I will do it if I find a free time).